# shinyapps.io error with external libraries

Tags: r, deployment, web-deployment, shiny

I'm trying to deploy a Shiny app. It works perfectly locally. But when I deploy it to the web, I get the following log for each external package:

```
shinyapps[66880]: Loading required package: XLConnect
shinyapps[66880]: Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
shinyapps[66880]:   there is no package called ‘XLConnect’
```

My server.R is like:

```
library(shiny)
library(XLConnect)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { .....
```

My ui.R is like:

```
library(shiny)
library(XLConnect)

shinyUI(navbarPage("Perspective:", .....
```

Any ideas appreciated!